# redux-observable offline/optimistic behaviour

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-observable

Is there any plans to enhance redux-observable with offline characteristics? It would be good if any behaviour like [redux-offline](https://github.com/jevakallio/redux-offline)/[redux-optimistic](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/redux-optimist) offer at the moment: revert store changes on request failure.

What is the best way to do that? I'm tempted to combine redux-observable with any of those libs and use it where needed. On the other hand I love working with observables :)

Answer (score 4):

redux-observable's goal is only to enable you to use RxJS with redux. Someone could build other things on top of it, like offline, transactions, etc, but it's outside the scope of redux-observable itself.

We also wanted to make sure that you could indeed use other middleware at the same time, so if you wanted to use either of those you certainly can.

Comment: Did this adequately answer your question? :)